# What kind of neural network be used to approximate sin(x) function?

Tags: neural-networks, network

Since neural networks are universal function approximators, I am interested to know if a neural network with a simple activation function be used to approximate $\sin(x)$ Assuming the input is bounded.

Comment: Depends on exactly what you mean. For instance, may we assume the input is between $0$ and $2\pi$? Because approximating the sine function on all of $\Bbb R$ is not going to work well with a finite network of ReLU nodes. And what exactly would you consider a "good" approximation?

Comment: @Arthur, yes we can assume that. I had a notion of just using step function but if the input is itself perodic then I think I would still get the intuition. By good approximation I mean roughly the shape of sinusoid.

Comment: Also when you say "not going to work well with a finite network of ReLU nodes" what are you pertaining to? Are you pertaining to something like taylor series where we would need infinite terms to make it work well?

Comment: I'm mostly thinking about the fact that if you have only ReLU nodes, then the functions you can make are piecewise linear. And if you only have finitely many of them, then there can only be a finite number of pieces. Whatever the final piece does, it won't approximate the sine function very well. It is easier to deal with a bounded domain.

Comment: Alright, makes sense. So by bounded domain you mean something like sigmoid right. Lets say we do have a compact support function, what would you choose and will it be able to approximate the sine function well. I an accept that as an answer.

Comment: No, sigmoid has bounded _range_. Bounded domain means limit what input values we use to something bounded, like $[0, 2\pi]$.

Comment: Yes, i got it. Ill have updated the question. I also removed ReLU as a node.

Comment: From the wording of your question, I'm guessing you already know about this, but you may want to look into the [Universal Approximation Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_approximation_theorem).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With ReLU nodes, it is quite straight-forward to make triangular waves. For instance, if you have a layer of hidden nodes given by
$$
\begin{align}
a&: x\mapsto R(x)\\
b&: x\mapsto R(x-1)\\
c&: x\mapsto R(x-2)
\end{align}
$$
(where $R$ is the ReLU function) and then combine them like so in the output node:
$$
a -2b + c
$$
then this gives a function which is flat to the right of $0$, then goes straight up to the point $(1, 1)$, then straight down to $(2, 0)$, and from there it's flat. Which is to say, a single triangle with base along the $x$-axis of length $2$ and height $1$.

The main insight is that this triangle may be moved and scaled appropriately by changing the input linearly or scaling the output. For instance,
$$
\begin{align}
a&: x\mapsto R(x)\\
b&: x\mapsto R\left(x-\frac\pi2\right)\\
c&: x\mapsto R(x-\pi)
\end{align}
$$
and changing the output node to
$$
\frac2\pi(a-2b+c)
$$
gives you a triangle that aligns with the first half of a sine wave. Similarly, you can make a triangle for the second half of the sine wave, add them together, and get [this result](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+sin%28x%29+versus+2%2Fpi*%28relu%28x%29+-2*relu%28x-pi%2F2%29+%2B+relu%28x-pi%29+-+relu%28x+-+pi%29+%2B+2*relu%28x-3pi%2F2%29+-+relu%28x-2pi%29%29%2C+x+from+0+to+2pi). Which is a good start.

So, if we want to do better, what can we do? Well, let's look at what's left. In other words, the difference between what we want and what we have. [Here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+sin%28x%29+-+2%2Fpi*%28relu%28x%29+-2*relu%28x-pi%2F2%29+%2B+relu%28x-pi%29+-+relu%28x+-+pi%29+%2B+2*relu%28x-3pi%2F2%29+-+relu%28x-2pi%29%29%2C+x+from+0+to+2pi) is a WolframAlpha plot of that. How can we fix this? More triangles!

This time we need four triangles. And at this stage we can choose our approach a little. Note that the waves here aren't completely symmetrical, so the maxima and minima aren't smack in the middle of the zeroes. Do we keep using symmetric triangles? That would make our expressions and our job a bit easier. If so, how tall do we make them? Or do we make triangles whose maximum coincides with the maximum of what we're after? Or maybe there is some other "best triangle fit" to look for.

I'll go for the symmetric triangles, with peak at the same height as the extrema. The first triangle is thus given by
$$
\begin{align}
d&: x\mapsto R(x)\\
e&: x\mapsto R\left(x-\frac\pi4\right)\\
f&: x\mapsto R\left(x-\frac\pi2\right)
\end{align}
$$
and to our output node we now add
$$
0.26803432(d - 2e + f)
$$
to account for the first wave. And we can make similar triangles for the remaining waves. Unfortunately, WolframAlpha won't let me plot the result of all of them, so [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+sin%28x%29+versus+2%2Fpi*%28relu%28x%29+-2*relu%28x-pi%2F2%29+%2B+relu%28x-pi%29+-+relu%28x+-+pi%29+%2B+2*relu%28x-3pi%2F2%29+-+relu%28x-2pi%29%29%2B0.26803431961*%28ReLU%28x%29+-+2ReLU%28x-pi%2F4%29+%2B+ReLU%28x-pi%2F2%29%29%2C+x+from+0+to+2pi) is a plot using only the first of these four. You can see how we're already really closing in on the sine graph.

Speaking of choosing better-fitting triangles, though, maybe we should look for a better fit in the original two triangles as well? Perhaps using [$0.8105695$ as a scaling constant in the output node](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+sin%28x%29+versus+0.8105695*%28relu%28x%29+-2*relu%28x-pi%2F2%29+%2B+relu%28x-pi%29+-+relu%28x+-+pi%29+%2B+2*relu%28x-3pi%2F2%29+-+relu%28x-2pi%29%29%2C+x+from+0+to+2pi) is a truer approximation than $\frac2\pi$, as the two waves now have approximately the same area. Or maybe we want the maximal difference between the values to be as small as possible, rather than the areas as equal as possible? In that case, we want to use [$0.724611$ as a scaling factor](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+sin%28x%29+vs+0.724611*%28relu%28x%29+-2*relu%28x-pi%2F2%29+%2B+relu%28x-pi%29+-+relu%28x+-+pi%29+%2B+2*relu%28x-3pi%2F2%29+-+relu%28x-2pi%29%29%2C+x+from+0+to+2pi).

Comment: +1 for insightful answer. I makes lots of sense now.

Comment: Your choice, but you may also want to add $\frac{24}{\pi^3} \approx 0.774$ as the scaling constant for the two-triangle setup that minimizes the sum of squares error. Also, the exact form of the first constant (for the same area) at the end is $\frac{8}{\pi^2} \approx 0.811$

Comment: @VarunVejalla Cool, thanks. Yeah, I was just fooling around with WA. It was late at night and I didn't really think about getting exact values.

Comment: I just have a side question, what choise of activation function would have given good smooth continuous approximation to sin function? sigmoid? I am just surprized that ReLU is used often eventhough its just piece-wise continuous

Comment: @GENIVI-LEARNER The sine function itself isn't unheard of as an activation function. But other than that, sigmoid and arctan are probably the most common smooth activation functions. You can still combine two arctans or two sigmoids to make a bump, and tweak a bunch of bumps to fit the sine function.